# How to send HTTP Request Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, httprequest

I have written tests using Selenium WebDriver and I have problems with authentication to the website. For Chrome and Firefox I've used a basic authentication from URL:

```
WebDriver.get("https://u:p@example.com/");
```

And it works fine, it bypasses the authentication popup and my test proceeds to the website.

In Explorer and Edge I cannot use this feature as it is disabled.
I tried to use Robot and it works for Explorer, but in Edge the test is stuck on the authentication window, it does not send any keys to the username or password fields.

```
WebDriver.get("https://example.com/");
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
Thread.sleep(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
Thread.sleep(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Right now I've tried a http request:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://example.com/");
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("u", "p"), "UTF-8", false));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
System.out.println(httpResponse);
WebDriver.get("https://example.com/");
```

And I get this response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK for successful login

But when the webdriver goes to page I still get an authentication request.

How can I bypass authentication window and login to the website in Edge and Explorer, any thoughts?

Comment: Just a quick note on that last part, the initial http request has nothing to do with the webdriver and whatever it does. So a successful http request will have no impact on anything happening with the webdriver.

Comment: Is there any way to bind my request with webdriver so i log in to website?

Comment: Try the answer I posted below and see if it works for you. I'm not sure if there is a way to bind requests like that unfortunately. At least nothing easily done.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in IE for me for dealing with a login popup. Give it a shot.
It basically waits for the login box to appear, and then attempts to login using that box. Fairly simple.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Alert login = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
login.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("user","pass"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this works only in explorer, i still need a solution for edge :(